# My Kindle Fire is stuck at the yellow triangle screen after installing TWRP. How can I fix this?

Tags: fastboot, amazon-kindle-fire, unbricking, twrp

I followed the i[nstructions on the official TWRP](http://www.teamw.in/project/twrp2/79) site on how to install TWRP on the Kindle Fire. So I did

```
wget <twrp.img>
adb shell idme bootmode 4002
fastboot -i 0x1949 flash recovery <twrp.img>
```

But now, my Kindle Fire wont boot. It just shows a yellow triangle. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reset the bootmode. This can be easily done with `fastboot`. Execute the following commands:

```
fastboot -i 0×1949 oem idme bootmode 4000
fastboot -i 0×1949 reboot
```